# I'm looking for a way to replace a cell if specific critera exist in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Attached below is a sheet that will show what I am talking about here. But this is what I am looking for. As you can see in sheet in Final shows all the list in a nice neat order.

This is what the end user sees. Now in some cases when a document like the Orig is sent to me, I need to import new lines if there are any. What I have been noticing though is that although the line are almost completely the same the client comments are different.

And with how comments are entered in red by us on the Final sheet, I just can't copy and replace everything. What I want to do is replace only the client comments and the required ship date.

I'd like to refrence the PO, the Part, and the Description as refrence points, and then replace the client comments and the required ship date with the new one, even if there isn't a change, I still would like to have it replaced as a just in case senario.

Can someone show me a script in VBA that will do that?

I thought about using something like this to do it:

```
With Intersect(wsJL.UsedRange, wsJL.Columns("Q"))
        .AutoFilter 1, "<>Same"
        With Intersect(.Offset(2).EntireRow, .Parent.Range("B:U"))
            .Copy wsJAR.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            .EntireRow.Delete
        End With
        .AutoFilter
    End With
```

But I am running into an issue where this isn't an EntireRow concept, but two individual cells not together, otherwise it would be a lot easier for me.

Is there a way of using this script or another one like it to get the results I am looking for?

Thanks for your help in advance if you can offer any.

[Example Sheet](http://kaboomlabs.com/excel/examples/SwitchCells.xlsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

Did something a little different, not how I wanted, but it's the easiest answer. Added two cells at the end of the data of the final tab:

**For O2-O4**

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Orig!$J$2:$J$4,MATCH(1,INDEX((Orig!$B$2:$B$4=$A2)*(Orig!$D$2:$D$4=$B2),0),0)),"")`

**For P2-P4**

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Orig!$E$2:$E$4,MATCH(1,INDEX((Orig!$B$2:$B$4=$A2)*(Orig!$D$2:$D$4=$B2),0),0)),"")`

and then created a new script:

```
Option Explicit

Sub One()

    Dim wsFIN As Worksheet 'Final
    Dim wsORI As Worksheet 'Original
    Dim lastrow    
    Set wsFIN = Sheets("Final")
    Set wsORI = Sheets("Orig")

        lastrow = wsFIN.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        wsFIN.Range("O2:P" & lastrow).Copy wsFIN.Range("I2:J" & lastrow)
        wsFIN.Range("I2:J" & lastrow).Borders.Weight = xlThin
        wsFIN.Range("I2:J" & lastrow).Font.Size = 12
        wsFIN.Range("I2:J" & lastrow).Font.Name = "Calibri"

End Sub
```

It works, but I was hoping for something a little cleaner.  Here is the end result.

[Solution](http://kaboomlabs.com/excel/SwitchCells.xlsm)

Answer (score 0):

Well if I've understood what you require, there isn't a simple 4-line answer to this one. But it's a simple 90-line answer. You will need to keep the Enums in line with the column definitions on your two sheets, "Final" and "Orig". And you may need to change the range definitions (sheet names etc). You'll need to do VBE Menu/Tools/References and check "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" to get the dictionary object. Sorry if it seems wordy, but it should be easy to maintain.

```
Option Explicit

' This is the definition of the columns on "Final" sheet
Enum final_record
    fr_partid
    fr_descr
    fr_vendorid
    fr_po
    fr_due
    fr_quantdue
    fr_status
    fr_orig
    fr_desired
    fr_comment
    fr_dayslate
    fr_pri
    fr_shoporder
    fr_remarks
    fr_end
End Enum

' This is the definition of the columns on "Orig" sheet
Enum orig_record
    or_po
    or_partid
    or_vendorid
    or_descr
    or_comment
    or_status
    or_quant
    or_balance
    or_orig
    or_requested
    or_end
End Enum

Sub UpdateDescrAndShipDate()
' Update comments and required ship date if matches po/partid/description.
' Else add a new row.
Dim lRows As Long, lRow As Long, rFinal As Range, rOrig As Range, sKey As String
Dim lTarget As Long, lNew As Long
Dim dictTarget As New Scripting.Dictionary

' Get Final rows into dict by key
    Set rFinal = Worksheets("Final").Range("A1")

    lRows = rFinal.Offset(65000, 0).End(xlUp).Row - rFinal.Row
    For lRow = 1 To lRows
        sKey = rFinal.Offset(lRow, fr_po).Value & "|" & _
               rFinal.Offset(lRow, fr_partid).Value & "|" & _
               rFinal.Offset(lRow, fr_descr).Value

        If Not dictTarget.Exists(sKey) Then
            dictTarget.Add sKey, lRow
        Else
            MsgBox "Invalid duplicate key? " & sKey
        End If
    Next
    lNew = lRows

' Run through Orig rows, and write to Orig based on key value
    Set rOrig = Worksheets("Orig").Range("A1")

    lRows = rOrig.Offset(65000, 0).End(xlUp).Row - rOrig.Row

    For lRow = 1 To lRows
        sKey = rOrig.Offset(lRow, or_po).Value & "|" & _
               rOrig.Offset(lRow, or_partid).Value & "|" & _
               rOrig.Offset(lRow, or_descr).Value

        If dictTarget.Exists(sKey) Then
' update
            lTarget = dictTarget(sKey)
            rFinal.Offset(lTarget, fr_comment).Value = rOrig.Offset(lRow, or_comment).Value
            rFinal.Offset(lTarget, fr_desired).Value = rOrig.Offset(lRow, or_requested).Value
        Else
' new row
            lNew = lNew + 1
            rFinal.Offset(lNew, fr_partid).Value = rOrig.Offset(lRow, or_partid)
            rFinal.Offset(lNew, fr_descr).Value = rOrig.Offset(lRow, or_descr)
            rFinal.Offset(lNew, fr_vendorid).Value = rOrig.Offset(lRow, or_vendorid)
            rFinal.Offset(lNew, fr_po).Value = rOrig.Offset(lRow, or_po)
            rFinal.Offset(lNew, fr_due).Value = rOrig.Offset(lRow, or_balance)
            rFinal.Offset(lNew, fr_quantdue).Value = rOrig.Offset(lRow, or_orig)
            rFinal.Offset(lNew, fr_status).Value = rOrig.Offset(lRow, or_status)
            rFinal.Offset(lNew, fr_orig).Value = ""
            rFinal.Offset(lNew, fr_desired).Value = rOrig.Offset(lRow, or_requested)
            rFinal.Offset(lNew, fr_comment).Value = rOrig.Offset(lRow, or_comment)
            rFinal.Offset(lNew, fr_dayslate).Value = ""
            rFinal.Offset(lNew, fr_pri).Value = ""
            rFinal.Offset(lNew, fr_shoporder).Value = ""
            rFinal.Offset(lNew, fr_remarks).Value = ""
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```